# After successful db.collection.update always error is thrown

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Am using Node.JS to update my collection data based on a logic.
The update happens as expected but in my console after the update it is not returning proper values. It is always returning errors. Below is the code snippet

```
db.collection('test').update(query,operator,options,function(err,docs){
                    if(errs) {
                        console.log('something went wrong somewhere');
                    }
});
```

The above snippet always prints something went wrong somewhere. Does that mean that the update is not successful.

I use MongoClient along with Node.js.

P.S: Newbie to MongoDB learning via 10gen courses

Comment: It probably means something is wrong but we would need many more specifics to debug it, first off what `errs` is.  Actually seems like that should never be logged since `errs` is undefined, but may just be a typo.

Comment: errs is the callback return value of error in case if the update does not happen properly.

Comment: The content of `errs` (or `err` as you show it in the callback parameters) will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah but the update is also successful that is why confusion. What am I going wrong. After the update block I have just closed the db with db.close

Comment: I am not sure wether you are supposed to close the connection. Usually, MongoDB drivers maintain a connection pool.

Comment: Please print `errs` so we can see what it says.